# can i use loop so if the user enters wrong user or password he have to try again

Tags: python, loops

can i use loop so if the user enters wrong user or password he has to try again

```
    users = {
    'Django': {'id': 3, 'pass': '1234', 'fname': 'Brenda', 'sname': 'Miles', 'age': 31},
    'KnightWhoSayNi': {'id': 12, 'pass': 'abcd', 'fname': 'William', 'sname': 'Johnes', 'age': 27},
    'Donald99': {'id': 45, 'pass': 'AbCd', 'fname': 'Donald', 'sname': 'Cole', 'age': 19},
    'stuntman': {'id': 9, 'pass': 'password', 'fname': 'Gareth', 'sname': 'Timberlake', 'age': 23},
    'DarkPrincess': {'id': 5, 'pass': 'lie2me', 'fname': 'Kate', 'sname': 'McBride', 'age': 65},
    'aaron': {'id': 28, 'pass': 'ilovescience', 'fname': 'Jessie', 'sname': 'Pinkman', 'age': 29}
    }

user_name = input('Please enter your username: ').strip()
if user_name in users.keys():
    password = input('Please enter your password: ').strip()
    if users[user_name]['pass'] == password:
        print(f"Welcome back, {users[user_name]['fname']} {users[user_name]['sname']}!")
    else:
        print("The password you entered is incorrect!") 
else:
    print("Sorry the username does not exist in the database :(")
```

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the whole thing in `while True`, and add a single `break` statement.

```
while True:
    user_name = input('Please enter your username: ').strip()
    if user_name in users.keys():
        password = input('Please enter your password: ').strip()
        if users[user_name]['pass'] == password:
            print(....)
            break
        else:
            print("The password you entered is incorrect!") 
    else:
        print("Sorry the username does not exist in the database :(")
```

Comment: Gosh.  Someone votes me down on this without leaving a comment and the original poster thanks me.   I'm confused.